# Codeigniter 2 not returning from model as object only as result array

Tags: php, codeigniter, resultset, codeigniter-2

So, i've been using codeigniter for a while and I've never had an issue running a query in my model and returning it to my controller which then passes it into my view where I access it as an object, like so:

MODEL (somemodel)

```
function getdata()
{
  $query = $this->db->get('sometable');
  return $query;
}
```

CONTROLLER (somecontroller)

```
function controldata()
{
  $this->load->model('somemodel');
  $data['dbdata'] = $this->somemodel->getdata();
  $this->load->view('someview',$data);
}
```

VIEW (someview)

```
<?php 
foreach($dbdata->result() as $row) {
  echo $row->id;
  echo $row->name;
  echo $row->whatever;
  echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

But now for whatever reason in 2.0 it's making use $dbdata->result_array() as $row instead.

Basically it's returning the results as an array instead.

It doesn't make any sense, has something changed in the new version?

Thanks,

So here's my code:

MODEL (admin_model)

```
function show_allproducts($sort,$order,$limit,$offset)
{
    $this->db->select('products.id,productcategories.categoryname,products.name,products.internetspecial,products.added,products.modified');
    $this->db->from('products');
    $this->db->join('productcategories','products.productcategories_id = productcategories.id');
    $this->db->order_by($sort,$order);
    $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);

    $query = $this->db->get();        

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER (admin)

```
function show_allproducts()
{
    $data['title'] = 'All Products';

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/admin/show_allproducts';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('products')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['num_links'] = 5;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="paggination right">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&lt;&nbsp;prev';
    $config['next_link'] = 'next&nbsp;&gt;';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<a class="active">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $data['tabledata'] = $this->admin_model->show_allproducts('name','ASC',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));

    $data['nav'] = 'admin/pagesections/nav';
    $data['maincontent'] = 'admin/pages/show_allproducts';

    $this->load->view('admin/template',$data);
}
```

VIEW (show_all_products)

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <?php if($tabledata) { ?>            

        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>CATEGORY</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>ADDED</th>
        </tr>

        <?php foreach($tabledata->result() as $row) { ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->categoryname; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->added;) ?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php } ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>NO DATA</td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok folks, no lie, I found the freaking problem.

Looking at the fourth td where $row->added; is at, there's a close parantheses at the end of it that was causing 4 days of mayhem.

Kindest regards to all those who tried to help. Sometimes it doesn't matter how many eyes are on it I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you specify **$dbdata->result_array() as $row** , It wont return the results as array. The same code which you've posted must be working in CI 2.0.

If not, may be the problem with **$this->db->get('sometable')**.

Try with **$this->db->query('select * from sometable')**. But as far as i know, both are same...

Comment: This is correct. The code should work in CI2.0 without issues. You need to use result_array to get an array of arrays. Otherwise the result is an array of objects. More here : http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: You're preaching to the choir. I can't figure out why it's acting the way it is. If use $dbdata->result_array() as $row it works. If I use $dbdata->result as $row, it does not work. I'll edit my text above to include the actual code.

Comment: Anyone had a chance to check it out?